# append values to data frame using cbind

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a dataframe called `glen` which has this form(that's a part of it)

```
  X   Y  Z
 334 213 A  
 123 342 B  
 324 344 C  
 234 231 D  
 643 575 E
```

i'm applying a function on this data this will generate for each value of Z multiple rows.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(glen))
{
fin <-  cbind(fin,name=glen[i,]$Z, ...ETC)

}
```

so the output of `fin` should be somehing like:

```
Z V1 V2
A  5 6
A  1 4
A  4 2
A  8 6
B  2 7
B  5 4
C  2 4
C  9 5
```

but after the for loop is finished, i only have the last values of the `fin` data frame:

```
C  2 4
C  9 5
```

what should i do to fill all the values inside the `fin` data frame.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to figure out exactly how you got from the values in `glen` to the values in `fin` (someone can let me know what simple mapping I was too slow to get), here's a suggestion:

```
glen <- data.frame(X=c(334,123,324,234,643),Y=c(213,342,344,231,575),
  Z=c("A","B","C","D","E"))

finList <- apply(glen, 1, function(x) {
  myName <- x["Z"]
  myVal1 <- as.numeric(x["X"])-c(1:4)
  myVal2 <- 5:8
  return(data.frame(Z = rep(myName, length(myVal1)), V1 = myVal1, V2 = myVal2))
})

fin <- do.call("rbind", finList)
```

In general, it's probably good to avoid growing an object in a `for` loop, especially if `glen` has a lot of rows.

Also, you `cbind` the results of each iteration in the `for` loop, but the example `fin` looks like you really want to `rbind`.

Also2, is each value of `glen$Z` unique?

**EDIT**

Added line in `apply` to show calculation based on glen. The object `x` in the anonymous function called in `apply` is the portion of `glen` that is being passed to the function. You could even perform calculations based on the entire data set `glen` within the function, but it would be very helpful to know what calculations you want to perform for each row.

**EDIT 2**

Here is an example that considers the comment below about an additional table df:

```
df<-data.frame(begin=rep(glen$X,each=5),
  finish=glen$Y-sample(-10:10,5*nrow(glen),replace=TRUE),
  Val1=rnorm(5*nrow(glen)))

finList <- apply(glen, 1, function(x) {
  myName <- x["Z"]
  myVal1 <- subset(df, begin==x["X"]&finish<=x["Y"])$Val1
  return(data.frame(Z = rep(myName, length(myVal1)), V1 = myVal1))
})

fin <- do.call("rbind", finList)
```

Comment: yes each value of glen$Z iz unique. but this will not work with me, the for loop is needed because i'm filling fin from the result of glen(something like a subset form glen but with each value of Z will have multiple rows, that's why i used a for loop). and btw the size of glen is around 25 rows, so it's not that big.

Comment: @ifreak, You should still be able to use the above code. Can you give an example of what operation you would like to apply to `glen`?

Comment: `for(i in 1:nrow(glen))
{
fin <- rbind(fin,Z=glen[i,]$Z, val=subset(df, begin=glen[i,]$X & finish<=glen[i,]$Y)$Val1)
}`
it's an operation based on another data frame, but this is the way i want to fill my fin dataframe

Comment: when i rbind the fin, i got the V1 and V2 as row names but i want them as col names.

Comment: @ifreak, Please see my second edit. To include `V2`, you can add the operations you would like to the function and then add them to the `data.frame` that gets returned. If you have additional information you can add to the original question, such as referencing an additional data.frame, please edit the question accordingly to help get you appropriate and helpful answers.

Comment: this did not work, i'm getting the same values for each Z in fin (4 values fo each Z and have the same value).

Comment: @ifreak, Sorry for the absence. Did you try the code under EDIT2? There is an example there of how to perform a calculation on `df` based on data in `glen`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9636/discussion-between-benbarnes-and-ifreak)